# how to pass class name to keyup event in jquery

Tags: jquery, this, keyup

I want pass input class name to keyup event, but `onkeyup="filter(this)"` also got error

how to pass it?

```
$('.dropdown-select ul').before('<div class="dd-search"><input id="txtSearchValue" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="filter()" class="dd - searchbox" type="text"></div>');
```

```
$('.dropdown-select ul').before('<div class="dd-search"><input id="txtSearchValue" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="filter('+this.classname+')" class="dd - searchbox" type="text"></div>');
```

Comment: `onkeyup="filter(this)"` / `function filter(el) { let clsName = el.className }`

Comment: What's the error?  What's `this` in `" + this.className + "`.  Did you try `.className` instead of `.classname`?

Answer (score 1):

To pass the class name of the input element to the filter function in jquery keyup event, you can use jquery event handling methods rather than inline event handlers.

```
$('.dropdown-select ul').before('<div class="dd-search"><input id="txtSearchValue" autocomplete="off" class="dd-searchbox" type="text"></div>');

// Attach keyup event handler using jQuery
$('.dd-searchbox').on('keyup', function() {
    var className = $(this).attr('class'); // Get the class name of the input element
    filter(className); // Call the filter function with the class name as an argument
});

function filter(className) {
    // Your filter function logic here
    console.log("filter with class name:", className);
}
```